# Git rebase I have to pull after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have 2 branches

master:
mainfile, file1

feature-branch:
mainfile, file2

Then I do:

```
git fetch
```

next

```
git checkout feature-branch
```

next

```
git rebase -i master
```

Then I squash all commits from feature-branch and resolve conflicts in mainfile. After this I have on feature-branch

mainfile, file1, file2

and then I have to `git pull`. After pull I have to resolve all conflicts from master for all commits in file1.

Why I have to pull and resolve conflicts in second rebase if after first rebase i have all changes from master in feature-branch and before rebase all my branches are up to date?

Comment: Do you `fetch` the `master` branch or also `pull` it?

Comment: squashing things seems awkward here... why do you need to squash anything if you rebased commits? are you sure you do not squash a master branch commit?

Comment: "then I have to git pull", why? Why do you have to git pull? Are you confused about the message git gives you when you try to push? If the branch is already on the remote, it has all your old commits, and git doesn't track that those commits were first rewritten as part of the rebase and then ended up in the squash. From gits point of view, there's a bunch of commits on the remote that you don't have, and commits locally the remote don't have, so the logical operation is to merge, hence it suggests to pull. Please verify if this is the reason you "have" to pull.

Comment: I do fetch and pull. It doesn't matter if I not squashing  it's the same effect. @LasseV.Karlsen probably you are right but what I should do to don't have to do second rebase? Should I push force?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I had wrong config. When I changed `git config pull.rebase true` to `git config pull.rebase false` it works now.